# How to permanently remove a default add-on

Tags: add-on, archipack-add-on

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the images, the addon has been removed from the folder. I didn't remove it, it was probably Blender, or the new PRO version of Archipack that I installed. No way for me to know.
However, now there is no ARCHIPACK in the ADDONS folder, while there is a ARCHIPACK_20.
I tried to close and reopen Blender, but the problem persists.
It's also fun that there is a REMOVE button for version 2.3.3 PRO, but no REMOVE button for the old version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender comes with a "Light" version of Archipack, you can't "Remove" it with a button like custom add-ons. This is true for all add-ons that come shipped with Blender.

The custom add-ons get installed into a separate folder (Appdata/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/2.xx/Scripts/Addons on Windows), while the "default" ones can be found in the blender installation location.

You can see the actual install location in the *File* field when expanding the Add-on informations. You can actually see it in the screenshot you posted.

To permanently delete a "default" add-on, go to the location mentioned in the *File* field and simply delete the corresponding folder or `.py` file. Next time you open Blender, it won't be loaded.